# Verify that the function is a probability Mass Function

Tags: probability

Consider $X$ as a discrete real random variable with probability density function

$$
p(x) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{\theta^x}{x|\ln(1-\theta)|} & \text{if } x=1, 2, ... \\
    0 & \text{another case }
\end{cases}
$$
With $\theta \in (0, 1)$
In fact, $X$ is said to have a logarithmic Fisher distribution. The idea is verify that the function $p(x)$ is a Mass function.

Consider the Maclaurin series expansion

$$-\ln(1-p)=p+\frac{p^{2}}{2}+\frac{p^{3}}{3}+\dots=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{p^{k}}{k}$$
From this, we can note that
$$1=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{\ln(1-p)} \frac{p^{k}}{k}$$

If we take $p=\theta$ and $x=k$ then

$$1=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{\ln(1-\theta)} \frac{\theta^{x}}{x}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|\ln(1-\theta)|} \frac{\theta^{x}}{x}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} p(x)$$

The last equality is true if $\ln(1-\theta)<0$, this implies that $1-\theta>0$ or $1>\theta>0$.

This is enough to prove the result, verify that such a sum takes the value of one? Anything else to add? thank you!

Comment: Seems good to me.